# Scrapy with dynamic captcha

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, captcha

I'm trying to break a `captcha` within a form from a website, but this captcha is dynamic, it doesn't have a URL instead it has something like this

```
src="captcha?accion=image"
```

What is the best option here? I have read something like using middlewares or something like that. Also I know it can be done with Selenium or Splash or another browser driver (screenshot), but i want to do it with just `Scrapy`, if it's possible of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a complete solution to *bypass* the specified `captcha` using [anticaptcha](https://pypi.org/project/python-anticaptcha/) and [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/).

Due to the dynamic of this `captcha`, we need to grab a print screen of the `img` element containing the `captcha`. For that we use `save_screenshot()` and `PIL` to crop and save `<img name="imagen"...` to disk (`captcha.png`).
We then submit `captcha.png` to `anti-captcha` that will return the solution, i.e.:

```
from PIL import Image
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, ImageToTextTask
from selenium import webdriver

def get_captcha():
    captcha_fn = "captcha.png"
    element = driver.find_element_by_name("imagen") # element name containing the catcha image
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    driver.save_screenshot("temp.png")

    x = location['x']
    y = location['y']
    w = size['width']
    h = size['height']
    width = x + w
    height = y + h

    im = Image.open('temp.png')
    im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
    im.save(captcha_fn)

    # request anti-captcha service to decode the captcha

    api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' # api key -> https://anti-captcha.com/
    captcha_fp = open(captcha_fn, 'rb')
    client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
    task = ImageToTextTask(captcha_fp)
    job = client.createTask(task)
    job.join()
    return job.get_captcha_text()

start_url = "YOU KNOW THE URL"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(start_url)
captcha = get_captcha()
print( captcha )
```

---

**Output:**

```
ifds
```

---

**captcha.png**

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- **Use it at your own responsibility (be smart)**;
- You can improve the code by handling exceptions properly;
- `anticaptcha` is a [paid service](https://anti-captcha.com/mainpage) (0.5$/1000 imgs);
- I'm not affiliated with `anticaptcha`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, but one more question, i'm using scrapy, there is not gonna be any problem when scrapy and selenium "share" the driver? in some kind of way?

Comment: You're very welcome. I normally use `selenium` and honestly don't know much about `scrapy`. You'll have to try it  I guess.GL!